# Change color of various ListView items in a single Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Is it possible to set different background colors for different `ListView` items in one `ArrayAdapter`

e.g.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ArrayAdapter.getCount(); i++){

    Color c;

    switch(i){
         case 0: c = Color.RED; break;
         case 1: c = Color.GREEN; break;
         default: c = Color.BLUE;
    }

    ListView lv = ArrayAdapter.getView(i); //I know this method does not exist  
    lv.setBackgroundColor(c);
}
```

I don't know how to manage this, sorry I'm a android beginner...

Comment: You'll actually want to do this in your draw method for the individual elements. You'll want to override it and first choose a color and set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the getView Method in your ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v= super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `getView` of your adapter, add this code:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null){
        // Inflate row view here
    }

    Color c;
     switch(position){
         case 0: c = Color.RED; break;
         case 1: c = Color.GREEN; break;
         default: c = Color.BLUE;
    }

    view.setBackgroundColor(c);
}
```

Comment: How to add the getView method to my adapter?

Comment: @SeseSchneider You should just override it as what I have done.